# Process hangs while trying to push Azure AppInsights metric

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using the Application Insights Python API to publish a custom metric for my application every 30 s.
This works fine for a while (up to several days), but then my Python script just hangs while trying to flush the data to Azure.

The Python code itself is fairly simple, and just this infinite loop:

```python
while True:
    count = get_connection_count()
    if count is not None:
        tc.track_metric("ConnectionCount", count, type=DataPointType.measurement, count=1)
        tc.flush()
    time.sleep(10)
```

A stack trace (below) shows the process is stuck on `tc.flush()`, waiting from an answer from the server.

If I look at the TCP connections for the process, I can see the process still has an open TCP connection to Azure; it just not getting any reply.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue? What would cause the Azure AppInsights to stop responding like this?

Alternatively, can a timeout be defined for the `tc.flush` call, so I can at least recover from an unresponsive endpoint?

Here's the stack trace I was able to extract:

```
  File "/var/lib/app-monitor/connectionMonitor.py", line 52, in <module>
        tc.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/applicationinsights/TelemetryClient.py", line 55, in flush
        self._channel.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/TelemetryChannel.py", line 71, in flush
        self._queue.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/SynchronousQueue.py", line 39, in flush
        local_sender.send(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/SenderBase.py", line 118, in send
        response = HTTPClient.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
        return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
        '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
        r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1089, in getresponse
        response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status
        line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
        data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
        return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len)
```

Comment: if this is only happening on one of the machines, i'd presume something about that machine is messed up, like bad https certs, or a proxy set or something that is preventing it from actually making the connection?  if you just manually connect to https://dc.services.visualstudio.com using anything else does it connect?  can you ping/traceroute it from that machine, etc?

Comment: No, this happens randomly on any VMs I spin up.

Comment: It usually works fine for several hours until the freeze happens.
Opening connections to dc.services.visualstudio.com works fine. As a matter of fact, whenever the Python process is frozen like this I can still see the open connection to dc.services.visualstudio.com, on port 443 using netstat.

Comment: that is very odd.  failure or success should be super quick, and i don't think the service tries doing keepalive or anything that would keep those connections open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion internally, there's a workaround, though not really a fix:
make sure that sockets have some kind of default timeout value to prevent them from hanging forever:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
```

note that this applies to any+all http calls from the script, so it isn't necessarily *ideal*, but does prevent things from hanging for a long long time.

Comment: Thanks @john . I did suggested this exact fix to a Microsoft contact I'm working with, and have been trying out this workaround for the last few days.
I does seem to "fix" the issue. FYI I am getting quite a few HTTP errors (500 and 503), but these are retried immediately, so they're not a problem.

Comment: Btw, are there any plans to provide an actually fix in the Python API? Either hard-coding a timeout value in the HTTP call, or even better have the ability to specify a timeout in the API?

Comment: lol, i didn't realize that thread work was the same :D.  no idea bout the python api.  if that's up on github you could probably put this as an issue there and or possibly explicitly set the timeout on the webrequest/etc done by the sdk there?

Comment: It's already there ([Flush gets stuck on Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Python/issues/16)), and that's exactly what I suggested in the latest comment :D

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there may be two reasons which will causing the issue.

1. Some limits on the number of metrics and events were exceeded in your application, please refer to the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-insights-limits) and catch the responce status code via Wireshark or Fiddler on Linux to check it. There are some error codes for this case which include 402 (Payment required), 429 (Too many requests), 503 (Service unavailable), etc.
2. You can always get information for Application Insights on that health and status of the service at http://aka.ms/aistatus to check whether the issue was caused by some operations for planned maintenance or issue resolving.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm not sure I'm hitting any limits on AppInsights though, because this Python script is run on quite a few VM, and if that was the case I would expect the problem to happen on all of them.

Also, looking at the stack, it looks like I'm not receivin any HTTP status message, error or not. I would expect urllib2 to throw if that were the case, don't you think?